# Etymology of "receta"

Tags: etimología

Both **receta** and recipe descend from a common Latin source, **receptus**. And **receptus** is the past participle of **recipiō**, which means to take or receive. This Latin word also evolved into receipt of English.

My confusion is how did the word for receipt evolve to become recipe and **receta**? There seems to be no bridge between them whatsoever!

Answer (score 2):

Both come from the latin `recepta`, but apparently Spanish one evoluted differently. However, from what I see in the RAE `recepta` is still accepted: http://dle.rae.es/recepta:

> recepta.
>
> (Del lat. recepta, t. f. de -tus, recibido).
>
> 1. f. Libro en que se llevaba la razón de las multas impuestas por el Consejo de Indias.
> 2. f. ant. Receta médica.

From what I see in [Evolución histórica del latín#Rivus non ríus, síbilus non sífilus](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evoluci%C3%B3n_hist%C3%B3rica_del_lat%C3%ADn#5._Rivus_non_r.C3.ADus.2C_s.C3.ADbilus_non_s.C3.ADfilus) it was common from the `/p/` to "fall", so it might be the reason.

See the etimology in Spanish and English in the following pages.

[Etimologias.dechile.net - receta](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?receta):

> La palabra "**receta**" viene del latín *recepta* y
>   significa "nota escrita detallando un procedimiento". Sus componentes
>   léxicos son: el prefijo re- (reiteración), *capere* (capturar,
>   agarrar, tomar), más el sufijo -to (que ha recibido la acción). Ver:
>   [prefijos](/latin/), [sufijos](/latin/?Sufijos),
>   [otras raíces latinas](/latin/?Raices), receptor y recipiente.

[Dictionary.com - receipt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/receipt?s=t):

> late 14c., "act of receiving;" also "statement of ingredients in a
>   potion or medicine;" from Anglo-French or Old North French receite
>   "receipt, recipe, prescription" (c.1300), altered (by influence of
>   receit "he receives," from Vulgar Latin *recipit) from Old French
>   recete, from Latin recepta "received," fem. past participle of
>   recipere (see receive ). Meaning "written acknowledgment of money or
>   goods received" is from c.1600.

As a funny thing, in Catalan it is said just `recepta`.